# Weird mesh drifting in pose mode

Tags: rigging

Help me, when I move armature in pose mode, some separated meshes like eyes, mouth, hair etc. moves very slow or not moves, simply when I move body with separated meshes they start to levitate or go inside https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t1ZMd8XeZfCHK6KZhkW-vbiCJhr005N9/view?usp=drivesdk

I tried parenting to the head, and weight painting, not helped

Comment: The head is probably part of another vertex group, you need to check in Weight Paint mode and remove it from any other group, maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/